Python tkinter | how do I center my button?
As a person who is new to Python I'm currently coding a CPS counter, but I can't seem to center my Click button.
Here is what I got so far:
from tkinter import *
from threading import Timer
import time

# CPS Counter Code

print ("This is a test showing how much Clicks Per Second you have.")
time.sleep(2)
choice = input("How many seconds do you want CPS timer to be?: ")
choice = int(choice) # duration of timer
turn = 0
cps = 0 # cps starts at zero
num = 0

window = Tk()
window.title('CPS Counter') 
window.geometry("800x600") 
window.configure(bg = 'gray7')

def clicks(): # overall cps
    global num
    cps = num/choice
    cps = str(cps) # converts cps to string
    print("Your record is " + cps + " CPS!")
trackcps = Timer(choice, clicks ) 

def addcps(): 
    global num
    num += 1

def runcps():
    global turn
    if turn == 1: 
        addcps()
    
    if turn == 0:
        trackcps.start() 
        turn += 1

button = Button(window,  # button customization
                text = 'Click!', 
                padx=200,
                pady=100, 
                font=("Ariel Bold", 32), 
                command=runcps,
                bg = "black",
                fg = "white") 
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER) # supposed to center the button (problem)
button.pack()


window.mainloop() # prevents window from closing

I tried doing button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER) but it still doesn't seem to center the button.
How Can I fix this?

Remove button.pack() since you have already called button.place(...).

I would caution against using sleep and input in a tkinter application. 1. The UI thread will hang for the duration of the sleep, and 2. input is really only useful in console applications (that is, apps without a UI). If you want to get user input, you can use an Entry widget or use something like tkinter's built-in simpledialog.askinteger or simpledialog.askfloat

Remove the "button.pack()" as you have already placed it there is no need to pack it again.
#### Code used above ####
button = Button(window,  # button customization
                text = 'Click!', 
                padx=200,
                pady=100, 
                font=("Ariel Bold", 32), 
                command=runcps,
                bg = "black",
                fg = "white") 
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER) # supposed to center the button (problem)
#button.pack()


window.mainloop() # prevents window from closing

